How do we flag or comment on a user's profile?
I came across this new user 'a-child-of-god' (https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/6377/a-child-of-god).
Like many new Stack Exchange users, his first questions and interactions needs some tweaking but then I saw his profile page.
In his description I think he doing a big no-no for a Stack-Exchange site.  He is promoting a way to circumvent the need to have 50 reputation points by deliberately entering a bad answer which, in many cases, will be turned into a comment by the moderators.
In my opinion, this  kind of systematic hacking of the SE format should not be allowed. But how?
Q: The same way we help new users understand the format for questions and answers, how can we comment on the content of their bio?   

We did allow flagging of user profiles. . . for about a week. It turns out people used the mechanism to seek revenge on users who "offended" them on the site. So the more typical thing to do is flag one of the user's posts or comments with an "other" flag for moderator attention.
One thing to keep in mind is that different parts of a user profile are have different levels of publicness. We hardly ever worry about content in a user's "About me" section because you have to dig around a bit to find it. In this case, the advice is perhaps unwise, but not offensive. If the same user was more public with their advice (say, in a comment), that would likely be deleted.
As an aside, the problem of letting people comment before other types of contributions is something I hope to solve.

Hmm - it's not much of a "hack" and it does depend on the value of the answer and how the mods handle these responses.
Not all "Thanks" or "I'm having the same problem" responses get converted to comments - most will just be deleted completely.
I admit that I do tend to be a little more lenient if I think the response has some value but isn't a full answer on its own and converting it to a comment may help the person whose post I've added the comment to.
